# HTML table with database data

Tags: php, database, html-table

I want my database data to be shown in a table. I have the following code but it just paste everything next to each other.

**CODE:**

```
<?php
include ("core/db_connectie.php");

$template = file_get_contents("main.tpl.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM platen";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$cName = "";
$cValue = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        $cName .= $columnName;
        $cValue .= $columnValue; 
    }
}

$template = str_replace("%%header%%", "<tr><th>". $cName ."</tr></th>", $template);
$template = str_replace("%%data%%", "<tr><td>". $cValue ."</tr></td>", $template);

echo $template;

?>
```

and in my HTML file I have:

```
<table>
   %%header%%
   %%data%%
</table>
```

The result I get is:

```
IDAlbumBandStijlMediumDatumPrijsIDAlbumBandStijlMediumDatumPrijs
1TestTestereRockLP2013-06-1202TestTestereRockLP2013-06-1213
```

but I want it to be like:

```
ID Album Band Stijl Medium Datum         Prijs
1  Test  Test Rock  LP     2013-06-1202  €10
2  Test  Test Rock  LP     2013-06-1202  €10
```

Comment: and how the generated html looks?

Comment: Look at the values of $cName and $cValue before you use str_replace().

Answer (score 3):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        $cName .= $columnName;
        $cValue .= $columnValue; 
    }
}
```

needs to be

```
$i=0;
$values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $values[$key][$i] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
reset($arr);
foreach(current($arr) as $key => $value){
   $cName .= "<th>" . $key . "</th>";  
}  
while ($curr_row = current($arr)) {
    $cValue .= "<tr>";
    while (false !== ($curr_field = current($curr_row))) {
        $cValue .= "<td>" . $columnValue . "</td>"; 
        next($curr_row);
    }
    next($arr);
    $cValue .= "<\tr>";
}
```

this is a modified version of functions provided in the comments of the (mysql_fetch_assoc function)[http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php]
and

```
$template = str_replace("%%header%%", "<tr><th>". $cName ."</tr></th>", $template);
$template = str_replace("%%data%%", "<tr><td>". $cValue ."</tr></td>", $template);
```

needs to be

```
$template = str_replace("%%header%%", "<tr>". $cName ."</tr>", $template);
$template = str_replace("%%data%%", "<tr>". $cValue ."</tr>", $template);
```

This is because each coloumn needs a seperate td or th tag.